# WordPress Plugin Development Idea? Is this possible? Am I on the right track?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm very new to WP development. I host a website which needs a list of trails (hiking, biking, etc) and I'd like to write a WordPress plugin to do it.

Can someone please tell me if I'm taking the right approach, and if what I'm proposing is possible.

I'd like the site to end up with an auto-generated and filtered index at http://example.com/trail-guide, and the discrete trail info pages at http://example.com/trail-guide/trailname. This data would all be stored in a single database table holding info for each trail, with an admin page for adding, editing, and deleting entries from here.

Is a WP plugin the best way to go about doing this, or should I be looking at something else?

Answer (score 0):

From the way you're describing, your best bet would be to [Register A Custom Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type). This can be done by adding to your existing theme's Functions.php file, or by creating a plugin.

If you don't plan on changing themes, my advice would be to just hardcode everything into your functions.php file. Otherwise, creating a plugin for this particular job would be the safest alternative.

Using this functionality in tandem with [Custom Meta Boxes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) and [Custom Taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) will allow you to keep everything organized within the Wordpress Framework with your own special data.

This means that these new posts can also be queried at any time through the standard Wordpress Loop or search box.

If you are uncomfortable with writing your own functions to extend your existing framework, you might want to look into some plugins like [GD Custom Posts And Taxonomies Tools](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gd-taxonomies-tools/) to manage your own.

Hope this helps.